# How to disable postback on an asp button and still run OnClick method?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, code-behind

Yes, it is possible to simply add a return false to the OnClientClick, but that's not doing a very good job since the function on the OnClick just stops working.

The function that i use on the OnClick property on the button takes data out of the database and does something with it. while i have that return false there, nothing is happening. When it's not there, the page keeps refreshing and nothing is done.

Please, if anyone got a way to block the postback without blocking the method on the OnClick property that'll be great!

HTML

```
 <asp:Button Text="Edit Ceredntials"  OnClientClick="ShowWindow('#EditDetails', 2500)" OnClick="GetUserData" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Can you use a HTML Button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't prevent a postback and still run the `OnClick` method. That's because `OnClick` runs on the server, and the only way it can execute is via a postback.

If what you're really trying to accomplish is preventing the page from losing state and refreshing, you should be using AJAX instead and a compatible server side framework, like [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadUserDetails(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/Users/2500',
        type: 'GET'
     })
    .success(function(userDetails){
        $("#FirstName").val(userDetails.FirstName);
        ShowWindow('#EditDetails', 2500);
    });
}
</script>

<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick='loadUserDetails()' Text="Edit Credentials" />
```

Comment: Can you not actually stop only the refresh part?

Comment: @YuvalRoth The refresh part *is the postback*. That's what a postback is, it's the form submitting back to the server. Like I said, if you don't want it to happen, you'll need to implement AJAX.

Comment: Alright, AJAX..... Sadly, i'm a beginner coder and i got absolutely no idea on how to use it. You're saying i'll be able to call the method using ajax, and run the javascript function on the same click on the same button? will i need an asp button for that? Can you show me an example with reference to my code on how to use it?

Comment: @YuvalRoth I've updated my answer to show what your client side might look like, though it's dependent on what frameworks you choose to use and what data you need to fetch from the server. It's too broad of a topic to show you exactly everything you need to do, but I suggest you watch some videos about using jQuery AJAX and ASP.NET Web API and check out their documentation.

Comment: All i really need is to call two functions, one javascript function, and one function in the code-behind.

Comment: @YuvalRoth And what does the code behind function do?

Comment: It sets the user details into html tags so the user could edit them, and then when he's done it posts back the data into the database

Comment: @YuvalRoth Well if you look at the sample code I posted, it shows retrieving the details about the user via AJAX and setting the value of an HTML element to one of those retrieved values. That satisfies the first part. The actual submission you can still do with or without AJAX.

Comment: God.... i just don't understand what you do here....  How can you actually take the data out of the database and then decide what to do with it using ajax? can't i simply only call the function using ajax? because the method is ready to be used. it only needs to be called somehow..

Comment: @YuvalRoth I don't understand your point, but it sounds like you need to spend some more time learning how the web, client/server interaction, and AJAX work. Those are critical skills to being a successful web developer, and not knowing them is going to prevent you from making nice applications.

Comment: @YuvalRoth: you asked earlier "will i need an asp button for that?" the answer is no. you can use an html button and `onclick` to call the javascript function. (i haven't read everything else in detail but i think the rest of the discussion still applies, unfortunately. it is not as easy as some people make it out to be.)